# React onChange event returns a TypeError: props.handleChange is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange, eventhandler

I created a simple class method called `handleChange` with a parameter of `id` under the class `App`.

I tried to call this `handleChange` method from a child function component called `TodoItem`.

When I clicked on the checkbox, the browser returned a `TypeError` saying that `props.handleChange(props.item.id) is not a function`, as shown in the pictures:

[image: props.handleChange is not a function]

Can someone explain what is wrong on my codes in `TodoItem`?

`App` class component:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem";
import todosData from "./todosData";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: todosData,
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange(this);
  }

  handleChange(id) {
    console.log("changed", id);
  }

  render() {
    const todoItems = this.state.todos.map((item) => (
      <TodoItem key={item.id} item={item} handleChange={this.handleChange} />
    ));

    return <div className="todo-list">{todoItems}</div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

`TodoItem` functional component:

```js
import React from "react";

function TodoItem(props) {
  return (
    <div className="todo-item">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={props.item.completed}
        onChange={(e) => props.handleChange(props.item.id)}
      />
      <p>{props.item.text}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TodoItem;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your constructor you're not properly binding your function

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todos: todosData,
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)//<-- This is right
    //this.handleChange = this.handleChange(this);//<-- This is wrong
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much to point out this simple mistake. I was troubleshooting but couldn't spot this. I must check my eyes thoroughly.

Answer (score 2):

You either need to bind `handleChange` on using or convert it into arrow functions. I prefer arrow functions.

binding;

```
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
```

arrow function;

```
handleChange = (id) => {
    console.log("changed", id);
}
```

P.S: if you don't change the item in the child component there is no point to pass item into child and pass item.id to props.handleChange since it is accessible in the parent component in the first place.

P.S.2: you actually invoke `handleChange` instead of binding it in your constructor.

Comment: Thank you, ilkerkaran, I did bind the handleChange inside constructor() under App.js as you can see in the code.

Comment: @user13145130 I think you forgot to bind tho `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);`